# can I store array of object in local-storage with the same property every time which is gonna stay even if I refresh the page in javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have written a program which takes inputs and store in **local storage** as an **object** into an **array**. until I don't **refresh** the page and give inputs, it makes a **NEW** array every time and put those input values with the **same property** into an object. bur whenever I **refresh** the page and run that function again, the local storage lose it's all previous data and start storing new data. although I didn't style the structure and didn't give any input validation. but jus insert inputs and check the local-storage and you will understand.
**How can I store those data into local-storage even if the page has been refreshed?**

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="regform">
        <div id="name">
            <h2 class="name">Name</h2>
            <input id="firstName" type="text" name="first" value=""><br>
            <label class="firstlabel" name="firstname">first name</label>
            <input id="lastName" type="text" name="last" value=""><br>
            <label class="lastlabel" name="lastname">last name</label>
        </div>

        <h2 class="name">Email</h2>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email">

        <h2 class="name">Password</h2>
        <input id="pass" type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off">

        

        <h2 class="name">Phone</h2>
        <input id="code" type="text" name="area_code">
        <label class="area-code">Area Code</label>
        <input id="number" type="text" name="phone">
        <label class="phone-number">Phone Number</label>
        
         <button type="submit" id="btnreg" >Register</button>

    </form>

    <script>
        var fname=document.getElementById("firstName");
var lname=document.getElementById("lastName");
var btn=document.getElementById("btnreg");
var password=document.getElementById("pass");
var mail=document.getElementById("email");
var ariacode=document.getElementById("code");
var pnumber=document.getElementById("number");


let datas = [];



var addData= (ev)=>{
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = {
        name: fname.value +" "+ lname.value,
        passcode: password.value,
        email: mail.value,
        phonenumber: "+"+ariacode.value +" "+ pnumber.value
    };
    datas.push(data);
    document.getElementById('regform').reset();

    var data_serialized = JSON.stringify(datas);
    localStorage.setItem("datas", data_serialized);
    var data_deserialized = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("datas"));

    
};
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
        btn.onclick=addData;
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Could you please paste your code? Otherwise it would be just guessing.

Comment: Sorry! I've posted the code. please take a look at it. although I didn't style the structure and didn't give any input validation. but jus insert inputs and check the local-storage and you will understand.

Comment: Ok. Thanks :-) 
If I get you right, the problem is, that after a reload the data is lost. Right?
In your code you just write the data, but never read from storage again (on initial load).

Comment: the problem is after a reload and inserting new data. you will see in the code that I've stored it with JSON stringify and also read from storage again using JSON.prse. but it's still lost it's previous data after a reload and inserting new data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the local storage to see if it's not empty before assigning new data to it? If you do not, you might be re-writing the local storage each time the page is refreshed. Please show your code.

Comment: Sorry! I've posted the code. please take a look at it. although I didn't style the structure and didn't give any input validation. but jus insert inputs and check the local-storage and you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a bit and now it works.
The problem was: You just overwrite the storage entry on every submit.
Solution: read existing entry, push new data, write new entry.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="regform">
        <div id="name">
            <h2 class="name">Name</h2>
            <input id="firstName" type="text" name="first" value=""><br>
            <label class="firstlabel" name="firstname">first name</label>
            <input id="lastName" type="text" name="last" value=""><br>
            <label class="lastlabel" name="lastname">last name</label>
        </div>

        <h2 class="name">Email</h2>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email">

        <h2 class="name">Password</h2>
        <input id="pass" type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off">

        

        <h2 class="name">Phone</h2>
        <input id="code" type="text" name="area_code">
        <label class="area-code">Area Code</label>
        <input id="number" type="text" name="phone">
        <label class="phone-number">Phone Number</label>
        
         <button type="submit" id="btnreg" >Register</button>

    </form>

    <script>
        var fname=document.getElementById("firstName");
var lname=document.getElementById("lastName");
var btn=document.getElementById("btnreg");
var password=document.getElementById("pass");
var mail=document.getElementById("email");
var ariacode=document.getElementById("code");
var pnumber=document.getElementById("number");


let datas = [];



var addData= (ev)=>{
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = {
        name: fname.value +" "+ lname.value,
        passcode: password.value,
        email: mail.value,
        phonenumber: "+"+ariacode.value +" "+ pnumber.value
    };
    
    var datas = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("datas"));

    datas.push(data);
    document.getElementById('regform').reset();

    var data_serialized = JSON.stringify(datas);
    localStorage.setItem("datas", data_serialized);
    
    
};
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
        btn.onclick=addData;
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```